# How to index a column with two values pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot, lookup

I have two dataframes:

**Dataframe #1**

Reads the values--**Will only be interested in NodeID AND GSE**

sta = pd.read_csv(filename)

[image]

**Dataframe #2**

Reads the file, use pivot and get the following result

```
sim = pd.read_csv(headout,index_col=0)
sim['Layer'] = sim.groupby('date').cumcount() + 1
sim['Layer'] = 'L' + sim['Layer'].astype(str)
sim = sim.pivot(index = None , columns = 'Layer').T
```

[image]

This gives me the index column to be with two values. (The header is blank for the first one, and Layers for the second) i.e 1,L1.

**What I need help on is:**

1. I can not find a way to rename that first blank in the index to 'NodeID'.
   I want to name it that so that I can do the lookup function and use NodeID in both dataframes so that I can bring in the 'GSE' values from the first dataframe to the second.

I have been googling way to rename that first column in the second dataframe and I can not seem to find an solution. Any ideas help at this point. I think my pivot function might be wrong...

This is a picture of dataframe #2 before pivot. The number 1-4 are the Node ID.

[image]

when I export it to csv to see what the dataframe looks like I get this..

[image]

Comment: what is your column name. is it Index?

Comment: when I do sim.index.name the output is blank

Comment: that is your index or column?

Comment: I use sim.index.name so that it can read me the name of the index column, but it returns as blank.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df.rename(columns={"Index": "your preferred name"})
```

if it is your index then do -

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.rename(columns={"index": "your preferred name"})
```

Comment: It still comes out blank :(

Comment: try df = df.reset_index()